# How to add external JS on index.html in React boilerplate?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-boilerplate

I am new in React JS. I have started with [React Boilerplate](https://www.reactboilerplate.com/).
I have a `js file` and want to use that file globally, so whenever I was trying to add a js file with script tag `<script src='' type='text/javascript'></script>` in index.html, it throwing an error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <.

So any suggestion?

**Note:** Import js file in each component is working but I don't want to include it in every component repeatedly.
I don't have any knowledge on webpack.

Comment: Check the src file for syntax error. This error is thrown usually when you miss tags or brackets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put JS File in assets folder, then import it in App.js

```
import ExternalJS from '../assets/externaljs.js';
```

This will be available in index.js.